# When I log in I can't do anything!

Tags: 12.10, unity, login, menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn’t load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Ok right when I login to Ubuntu 12.10 installed via Windows installer it [Ubuntu 12.10] shows the desktop background but not the menus, sidebar or the topbar I can't even start the terminal with the keyboard shortcut. I tried rebooting heap of times I even tried using the advanced options to repair broken packages.
I only just installed it yesterday.
Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I have previously rebooted about 5 time successfully.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you post the hardware specs of the machine: CPU, RAM, and most importantly, the graphics card.

Comment: HP Compaq 8510p. CPU:Intel Core 2 Duo t7500 @2.20Ghz x2. RAM:2Gb DDR2. Graphics card: ati 2600 256Mb 500Mhz+.

Comment: I am now happily running Ubuntu 12.10 installed with Ubuntu .iso which I installed on to a USB using [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/). One thing I found out is, it is important to make sure you have the right version for your computer cause I have always had trouble running Ubuntu because I was always using the 32bit version and even though it does work on a 64bit computer some 64bit computers won't like it [just don't try 64bit on a 32bit computer it doesn't work. Good way for noobs to find out which one their computers run on though ;) ] Thanks everyone!